# How does Django decide where to put the output of makemessages?

Tags: django, django-i18n

I have a Django app with several local locale folders, stored in the translations folder of the base directory:

- `translations/public/locale/{en,fr}`
- `translations/portal/locale/{en,fr}`
- `translations/terminology/locale/{en,fr}`

with corresponding entries in `LOCALE_PATHS`:

```
LOCALE_PATHS = (
  os.path.abspath(os.path.join(BASE_DIR, 'translations', 'public', 'locale')),
  os.path.abspath(os.path.join(BASE_DIR, 'translations', 'portal', 'locale')),
  os.path.abspath(os.path.join(BASE_DIR, 'translations', 'terminology', 'locale')),
)
```

It all works fine, but I don't know how to tell `makemessages` where to put its output. I don't see any relevant parameters in the source code. My preference would be to put the file somewhere else, like:

```
% bin/dev/manage.py makemessages -o .../derived_translations
```

How do I control, or at least determine where the output files are put?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It says it right in the help for `makemessages`:

> Runs over the entire source tree of the current directory and pulls out all
>       strings marked for translation. It creates (or updates) a message file in the
>       **`conf/locale`** (in the django tree) or **`locale`** (for projects and applications)
>       directory. You must run this command with one of either the --locale,
>       --exclude, or --all options.

So there you go, they will either be in the **`conf/locale`** or **`app_name/locale`** directories.

As for customizing the output directory, it does not look like it would be possible without writing a custom version of `makemessages.py`

Comment: Ah, I see. So if I were to make a `locale` directory in the base directory of the Django project, then makemessages will use it. That's what I needed, thank you.